# On which open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the $1$-form $(xdy-ydx)/(x^2+y^2)$ exact?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I think on an open set in the first quadrant not containing zero, there exists a function $f$ such that $df(x,y) = (xdy-ydx)/(x^2+y^2)$.

I think its like solving a differential equation with $x=rcos \theta$ and $y=rsin \theta$.

But I am not being able to do anything rigorous. Kindly help.

Comment: There is no such open set. $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ would not hold for such a  function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is exact differential, see
$$\frac{d \tan^{-1} (y/x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+y^2/x^2} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}, (x,y) \ne (0, 0)$$

Comment: That means it is exact on a set where $x$ is not zero, for example the set $\mathbb R^2 \backslash \{(0,y): y \in \mathbb R\}$ because this function is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: More apropriately $(x,y) \ne( 0, 0)$.